# PHP Fatal Error Sometimes - Live Site not Local Host

Tags: php, pdo

Okay I have searched and tried everything.  My site works perfect on localhost, I uploaded and am having Fatal Server issues like crazy.  I have narrowed it down to the following code.  The weird part this code works on some pages and others does not (same exact code!).

```
$stmt_RcdleagueinfoMENU= $eleaguehome->prepare("SELECT * FROM league WHERE leaguename = :league");
$stmt_RcdleagueinfoMENU->bindValue(':league', $curleague, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_RcdleagueinfoMENU->execute();
$row_RcdleagueinfoMENU = $stmt_RcdleagueinfoMENU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I get PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted....

Comment: You'll need to increase your allowed memory size in php.ini or limit the number of rows you are retrieving

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit' '-1')
```

PHP has a "memory limit" setting, and when you do $stmt_RcdleagueinfoMENU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) , you get so much data from the database that you're exhausting your current limit, which is set to ca 33.5MB (33554432 bytes)

```
ini_set('memory_limit' '-1')
```

= no limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit' '128M')
```

= 128 megabytes, and so on. see the "Resource Limits" section of the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

..be aware that a lot of free php webhosts (like Byethost or 000webhost, off the top of my head), does not allow you to change this limit.. if you want to confirm that you changed the setting, you can do like this:

```
assert(ini_set('memory_limit','128M')!==false,'128 megabytes of memory is required');
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help.  This query is also not a memory hog by any means, it is one table with about 15 columns and 1 row of data.

I think the problem might be related to I am using a variable for a table name. I found an issue on another page that makes no sense and the threads have taken me to the issue of variables and table names.

Comment: huh, that's strange.. what's the exact error you get? if you start the script with
error_reporting(E_ALL); assert(ini_set('memory_limit','128M')!==false,'128 megabytes of memory is required');

~~rest of script